# In a postgres loop, will the delete actually be performed at the end of the loop?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to delete a table, but I want it to be really delete at the end of the loop.

Could you confirm that if I code this way, the table will actually be deleted at the end of the loop?

```
do $$
    DECLARE
      _result_id integer; 
begin
delete toto;
    FOR _result_id  select id from tata order by id LOOP
insert into toto (id) value (_result_id);
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

the tata table contains data that comes from a CSV, with the COPY. This table is updated every 24 hours.

So I have to sort and insert the data into the toto table. I want to empty the toto table and make the new insert from tata to toto.
But I don't want toto to be empty to prevent the website from returning any information.

thank you

Comment: The **data in the table** will have been before the loop. And you don't need a loop.

Comment: Precisely, I want the data to be deleted after the loop. It is within the framework of a treatment of CSV. So I want to delete, insert but only at the end of the loop that the delette and the insert is done

Comment: It's unclear if by "delete" you mean the DML `DELETE`, the DML `DROP` or `TRUNCATE`. But you do use the DML `DELETE` in your code, so I just assume that's what you mean. It is however positioned *before* the loop, so no it won't be execute *after* the loop. `Deleting from `toto` after the loop would delete all the records inserted into it in the loop. So this seems overall a little pointless. Why insert and immediately delete afterwards? Maybe you can elaborate more on what your trying to do giving us some context to enabling us to give better answers.

Comment: In fact I do a data processing that I copy in a table just before. Then I have to reorganize the data and insert it into the table toto. This script runs every 24 hours.
So I have to delete the old data, then insert the new data from the tata table. But I don't want my toto table to be empty to prevent my website from returning any data ...

Comment: Post real code, no `(...)`, please!

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. If you want `toto` to stay empty, don't insert into it or drop it completely and don't create it again. It doesn't seem to serve any purpose anyway.

Comment: Exactly there I am reviewing my code so it is empty.

I made a copy in the tata table.
I want to sort my data and insert them in the toto table. Ok until then everything is good.

But to avoid managing the update, delete of my tata table, I want to delete toto and insert the data in toto, from the tata table. But without ending up with an empty toto table during all the processing of the loop. The loop runs on approximately 450,000 lines.

Comment: Toto must be updated every 24 hours with new data from the tata table which comes from a csv.

Comment: Instead of pasting pseudo-code, you should write a proper program, run it and then see for yourself what happens.

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this to begin with.

Comment: That's why I'm asking my question for confirmation ...

Comment: I loop on tata. For each line of tata, insert in toto ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need PL/pgSQL or an inefficient loop for this.

Just wrap the DELETE and INSERT into a single transaction without PL/pgSQL

```
begin transaction;
delete from toto;
insert into toto (id)
select id
from tata;
commit;
```

As this is a single transaction, changes are not seen by other transactions until you commit this. If anything fails, the transaction will be rolled back, including the `DELETE` and the `toto` table will look exactly like before.

Comment: pwaou I'm disgusted! I've been struggling with my loop for 1 week ... I didn't think about doing it like this !!! good i will test tonight! thanks a lot!
but yes, with the transaction I am sure that the delete will only be done if the insert went well.

it's even better!

thanks a lot

Comment: I forgot to say that I have 5 csv to link together (so 5 copies or 5 tables) to organize the data in toto. but i think the select with where should work

Comment: The run 5 `insert into toto ... select from ...` inside that transaction. Or join those 5 tables whatever you need to do to bring them together

Comment: I must leave, I am writing to you this evening.
Yes the id in the 5 tables is a url. In some table I have duplicates, so I think the best is to organize the 5 tables into 1 table to make my insert properly. I must also generate unique url according to the title (it is indeed a recipe)

Comment: and a table to manage the photos. So there may not be a picture, just one or several, in short, I'm looking at it tonight. sincerely thank you very much!